# ASP.Net Custom Authorize Attribute Incorrectly Redirects to Login Page in IE

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, forms-authentication

I wanted to show a custom access denied page when the user doesn't have the proper role to access a page so I created a custom AuthorizeAttribute.  This has worked well, but we had a strange issue come up.  One of our pages is using the default index action, and this one will redirect users to the login page when they are using IE.  This only appears to happen in IE and it only happens if the action is defaulted.  Meaning, the URL with /Area/Controller/Index works fine, but if you simply put in /Area/Controller it redirects to the login page.(specified in the forms tag in the web.config)  Another oddity is that this was happening consistently in a prod environment, but not in a test environment. There's nothing in the web.config  tags specific to the page and nothing funny that jumps out in the Route config for the area.(below)

Anyone know of any bugs or something else to investigate?(or maybe something quirky about the default action that may explain it)

```
 context.MapRoute(
                "TicketEntry_default",
                "TicketEntry/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );



  Here is the Authorize attribute:
public class AccessDeniedAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
    {
        public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
        {
            base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);
            if (!filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("/Login");
                return;
            }



if (filterContext.Result is HttpUnauthorizedResult)
        {
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult(filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest() ? "/Login/Login/AccessDeniedAjax" : "/Login/Login/AccessDenied");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Routes run in order from first registration to last, and the first match always wins. "Quirky" routing behavior usually can be attributed to matching the wrong route in the system by registering routes in the wrong order or not properly constraining them so they will will miss and try the next route in the collection. This issue can only be solved by seeing your entire route configuration along with the code you are using to generate the redirect URL. Most likely, it has nothing at all to do with the one route you have posted.

Comment: Is the example you provided the only route? If not ,then as @NightOwl888 suggested you need to look at the order in which you registered your routes and show some details (code) about  your configuration. Not much help can be offered without it.

Comment: What should I look for in the route?  The one I posted is the only one in that area and none of the others match the beginning "TicketEntry" part.  There is this default one below.  

context.MapRoute(
                "Root_default",
                "", 
                new { action = "Index", controller = "Dashboard", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );

Comment: I posted the Attribute.  I believe it is hitting the /Login redirect in the code.  I did notice that it redirects to /Login without the return URL.(which .Net would do by default if it was redirecting based on the web.config security rules)

Comment: Any other thoughts out there?  We had this issue pop up yesterday despite the workaround.  So, adding /Index must not always fix the issue.  Anyone know of an alternative or any reason IsAuthenticated would be false?